# Prompt for MFA code on certain AWS Cli actions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cli

We force MFA for AWS web console access. But I also want some aws actions to be prompted for MFA code.

```
aws iam delete-users --user-name theusername
Enter MFA: *********
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to add an MFA condition on the relevant API actions. For example, here's a IAM policy that allows the bearer to invoke EC2 actions freely, but requires MFA when invoking StopInstances or TerminateInstances.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": ["ec2:*"],
    "Resource": ["*"]
  },{
    "Effect": "Deny",
    "Action": ["ec2:StopInstances", "ec2:TerminateInstances"],
    "Resource": ["*"],
    "Condition": {"BoolIfExists": {"aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": false}}
  }]
}
```

For a more detailed example, see [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_mfa_sample-policies.html#ExampleMFADenyNotRecent).

Answer (score 1):

The exact use case is not possible. However, you can give the necessary permission e.g. StopInstances to an IAM Role and give the IAM user permission only to assume the role [if and only if the user uses MFA](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_mfa_configure-api-require.html#MFAProtectedAPI-cross-account-delegation). The role's trust policy will be as following:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": { "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:root" },
    "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
    "Condition": { "Bool": { "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "true" } }
  }
}
```

So while using the Console, IAM user will sign in with credentials and MFA token and will be able to assume the role to stop the instance.

While using CLI, you can use [named profiles with "mfa_serial"](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-roles.html#cli-roles-mfa) variable and when the user will try to stop the instance with the named profile parameter, the CLI will ask for the MFA code (note that the returned credentials will be cached in CLI).

Alternatively, you can use the suggestion provided by jarmod and use custom script because you need to call GetSessionToken and pass the MFA token. There is a sample Python and C# script [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_mfa_sample-code.html).